# Talend Open Studio for Data Integration - tSendMail - Generate HTML table in message body

Tags: talend

My requirement is to **generate html table** in message body of **tSendMail** component of Talend Open Studio for Data Integration.

Thanks.

Comment: you can try to generate html table by using html tags in a global string variable in talend and then assign that to tSendMail message body

Comment: I usually use a tXMLMap  to generate a html table, then store it in globalMap and use it in the sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly put HTML code in a tsend mail component.

like this example :

[Example](https://matthewmoisen.com/blog/tsendmail-html-in-talend/)

Answer (score 0):

The tSendMail component will accept straight HTML in the Message field, but you must make sure to configure Advanced Setting --> MIME type , setting it to HTML, or else the HTML will simply render as text.

[image]